# Updating data based on Select field works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: firefox, polymer

I'm posting this since I couldn't find an existing resolution for the issue I had for quite a while. When using Polymer 1.0, there was one page where the displayed data would change based on what the user selects from a dropdown menu (`<select>`). It worked perfectly in Chrome, but nothing would happen in Firefox, not even any requests would launch.

URL generation (just for example use):

```
<iron-ajax auto url="[[ targetUrl(templateName, id) ]]"
   handle-as="json" last-response="{{ template }}" id="dataPage"></iron-ajax>
```

Selection:

```
<select value="{{ templateName::input }}" class="form-control" id="page-data">
  <option value="data-one">Show dataset one</option>
  <option value="data-two">Show dataset of another thing</option>
  <option value="data-three">Show dataset for third choice</option>
</select>
```

Values:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ template.fields ]]" as="field">
  <li class="list-group-item list-item-draggable" data-value$="[[ field.value ]]">[[ field.name ]]</li>
</template>
```

Partial from the JS:

```
targetUrl(templateName, id) {
    return `/dataPage/template/${templateName}?id=${id}`;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in `<select value="{{ }}"`.

Chrome accepts `::input` as the event type, but it **does not work** in Firefox (46). In order to get it working in Firefox too, you need to use the event type `::change`.

Thus:

```
<select value="{{ templateName::change }}" class="form-control" id="page-data">
  <option value="data-one">Show dataset one</option>
  <option value="data-two">Show dataset of another thing</option>
  <option value="data-three">Show dataset for third choice</option>
</select>
```

Then it works equally in Firefox and Chrome. Hope this helps!